# Disable View Roles and Role Hierarchy and View Setup and Configuration in profile System Permissions

Tags: permissions, profile, system-permissions

I am trying to disable *View Roles and Role Hierarchy* and *View Setup and Configuration* **System permission** from a specific profile.

When I click on *Save* button after removing checks from the check box of these permissions, I get a confirmation box:

[image]

When I click on *Save* button on that confirmation box, nothing happens.

I am logged in with *System Administrator* and in the **QA** environment, the above stuff works fine in **Dev** environment.

**Tried using ANT too:**

I fetched the profile through **ANT**.

After *disabling* the above **System Permissions** in the meta-data file, deployed it to the Org.

The meta-data deployed successfully.

When I checked in the Org, the permissions are still *enabled*.

I fetched the meta-data again with ANT, the permissions were enabled there also.

What am I missing here?

Comment: To which profile are you making the change?

Comment: That is a custom profile